# ASTNodes And Views

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to know if there is a function that when i give it an ASTNode object (the ASTNode can be a class, method or a field in a CompilationUnit) as an argument it can show this object in a view (Tree view or Table view). If there isn't any such function, is there another way or workaround of doing it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the [ASTView plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are referring to Java or just something else. I'm assuming you need a Java tool. I'm not sure what exactly you expect to see in the "view".

Do check out [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/). It may be what you are looking for. Given any component in your code (like Class, field, etc.) it can show all possible associations to other components.